# Is the jewel even neccesary for A Dark Room on iOS?

Tags: a-dark-room

The first time I played through the game, I don't think I had jewels or knew about the murky swamp but still completed the story.

The second time, I realized I had jewels. Does this mean jewels aren't necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are not necessary. I passed it twice, once with building huts and once without, and I never used one.

Answer (score 0):

Jewels are not necessary but I guess they give you a better view of the game and the girl.